# Tensorflow segfault when using with numpy-quaternion library

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

The following code snippet crashes on the second last line, so where `tf.train.latest_checkpoint)` is called:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers import batch_norm as batch_norm
import quaternion

latest_checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint('checkpoints/default_model/run_000')
print(latest_checkpoint)
```

The ouput is:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
*** Error in `.../anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_env/bin/python': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000001c7a850 ***

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

I am using Python 3.5.2, Tensorflow GPU-version 0.12 in a conda virtual environment, Ubuntu 14.04. The `import quaternion` statement refers to the external library called [`numpy-quaternion`](https://github.com/moble/quaternion/blob/master/README.md).

The error does not happen if *either* the `batch_norm` or the `quaternion` import is omitted (so second or third line in the above snippet). Does somebody know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways to work around/fix the error:

**Don't import batch_norm**

Just always use `tf.contrib.layers.python.layers.batch_norm` directly in the code, thus omitting the import statement (admittedly, creates a lot of clutter).

**Set environment variable LD_PRELOAD**

The following fix posted by dennybritz on February 10th in [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6968) helped:

```
sudo apt-get install libtcmalloc-minimal4
export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4"
```

Note that if you're using PyCharm, you either have to specify this environment variable in the run configurations (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638974/pycharm-not-updating-with-environment-variables)) or - if you put the above export statement into your `.bashrc` - you have to start PyCharm from the command line so that it inherits the environment variables (as explained [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538859/pycharm-set-environment-variable-for-run-manage-py-task?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

However, while this fixes the issue, I don't know why this error occurs in the first place and if it should be considered a bug that should be reported to either tensorflow or numpy-quaternion devs.