# pycharm, set the environment variable for every project and script

Tags: environment-variables, pycharm

I have the same problem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638974/pycharm-not-updating-with-environment-variables).
And I can set the environment variable for a specific script in an specific project.
But how to set the environment variable for every project I open with pycharm?

What I want to do is, to set
/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64/ to LD_LIBRARY_PATH
for every project

Comment: Add one configuration file to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` ?

Comment: can you explain that in more detail please? I didn't understand