# Pycharm: set environment variable for google service account key (json credential)

Tags: python, pycharm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I want to run the google cloud speech python sample in my pycharm.

But encountered the

> ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

And I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22899916) but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

PS: The google sample can run in the terminal well.

Comment: Post your code, preferably as a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and the error that you get.

Answer (score 10):

Well I found the solution myself,

Based on the ver 2016.2.3

Run->Edit Configurations->Environment variables->add ur credential path in the "..." window