# I am unable to import tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, python-import, importerror

I pip-installed tensorflow by running the "pip install tensorflow" on my windows command prompt.

But when I try importing tensorflow and run a simple program on it:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x1=tf.constant(5)
x2=tf.constant(6)

result=tf.multiply(x1,x2)
print(result)
```

I get loads of errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 903, in create_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in
_call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/hp/PycharmProjects/untitled/trial.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 903, in create_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in
_call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help.
```

And the following errors are obtained

Comment: run tf.__version__ what do you see? in console

Comment: I get the same set of errors again

Comment: then it is not installed. are you using anaconda.

Comment: I am using pycharm

Comment: Hover tensorflow then press Ctrl+ enter to install package

Comment: Did you install the GPU version of TensorFlow? If so, the `%PATH%` environment variable for PyCharm might not include the CUDA and cuDNN DLLs. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21538859/3574081) has suggestions for how to set the environment variables appropriately.

Comment: Duplicate of this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370953/error-while-import-tensorflow-module/43566463#43566463

Answer (score 0):

These are the possible scenarios:

1. You need to install the MSVC 2019 redistributable
2. Your CPU does not support AVX2 instructions
3. Your CPU/Python is on 32 bits
4. There is a library that is in a different location/not installed on your system that cannot be loaded.