# Django can't recognize bash variable even if I export it - running virtual server from Pycharm

Tags: python, django, bash, environment-variables

I have an environment variable exported in bash. Project is in localhost. OS is `Debian 9 Stretch`.

When I run, in command line:

```
python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD'))"
```

I get the variable value.

But, inside Django, calling `os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD')` returns `None`.

In settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
```

Already find n similar questions, but in general the problem is that the variable wasn't exported to `environment`.

What I am missing?

**Update:**
Django virtual server is called directly from Pycharm

Comment: where is you environment variables set??

Comment: I'm setting it with `EMAIL_PASSWORD=password` and then exporting with `export $EMAIL_PASSWORD`. `printenv` returns it.

Comment: are you putting them in .bashrc file or .env file?

Comment: And how are you starting Django?

Comment: @Exprator, by now I'm only exporting in current environment not in `.bashrc`, but `printenv` displays that. Starting Django with `python manage.py runserver 8000`

Comment: There's no global environment. Variables must be exported from the parent shell before you start a child shell or child process. How and when did you export the variable? Have you exported the variable in the parent shell before starting runserver? [mcve]

Comment: Thanks @HåkenLid. It was missing the important information that I'm running Django virtual server from Pycharm. Pycharm doesn't know about environment variables from other shells. So that was the problem. I've been configure the environment variable in PyCharm Run/Debug Configurations -> "Environment variables", so now it works. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538859/pycharm-set-environment-variable-for-run-manage-py-task#21619127

Answer (score 0):

`export $EMAIL_PASSWORD` will not work. First remove the `$` and define the variable value in the shell, not only the variable name. It should look like this:  `export EMAIL_PASSWORD='value'`

**Edit**

Don't put the `''`around the var when you call it. Django will think its a string, not a variable.

Comment: I'm exporting with `export EMAIL_PASSWORD='value'`. Wrote comment wrong. Sorry.

Comment: if EMAIL_VARIABLE is a variable, don't put the ' ' around it, but use it as a variable, so no ' ', Django will see things in  ' ' as a string and you can't export a string (as you probably know)

Comment: see edit @Caco ! This may be the solution!